# Executing psql queries from a file vs passing it through bash

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to pass in queries to psql through an python script.

```
PGPASSWORD=pass -U postgres -d postgres -h localhost -c "insert into table1 values(1,2); select * from table2;"
```

Here suppose, the second query (select * from table2) fails, then the first query is also not applied(not sure if it is not applied or its effect is rolled back)
But if I have both of the queries in a file name <file.sql>

```
PGPASSWORD=pass -U postgres -d postgres -h localhost -m file.sql
```

then even if the second query fails, the first one is executed. Does the first method executes all the queries as one transaction and if one fails, it rolls back the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what happens.

The argument to `-c` is sent to the server as a single request, so it runs as a single transaction.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) says:

> Each SQL command string passed to -c is sent to the server as a single request. Because of this, the server executes it as a single transaction even if the string contains multiple SQL commands, unless there are explicit `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` commands included in the string to divide it into multiple transactions.

You can use the `-c` option more than once if you don't want that.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I tried looking for this,  can you point me to place in the documentation where I can read more about the parameters passed?

Comment: I have added the reference to the answer.